# Laravel Nova - Downloading a Generated File with an Action

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have the following have the following handle() method in a Nova Action:

```
public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
{
    $file = Excel::store(new \App\Exports\DownloadRiskConsequenceTemplate, 'risk_consequence_template.xlsx', 'public');
    $download = Action::download(Storage::url($file), 'risk_consequence_template.xlsx');
    return Action::message('Download started..');
}
```

I've tried quite a few iterations of getting this to download, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried Storage::url, storage_path(), url(), tried putting the file in /public, but none of it triggers the download and I get a "Failed - No file" error.

What is the correct way of handling an Excel download from a Nova Action?

Comment: What excel package are you using?

Comment: Laravel Excel by SpartnerNL

Comment: `return Action::download(Storage::url($file), 'risk_consequence_template.xlsx');` is it working?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use `$fields` or `$models`, the easiest solution is to let the action forward to a real controller:

```php
class ExportMyData extends Action
{
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        return Action::download(route('mynova.export.mydata'), 'myfile.ods');
    }
}
```

and call `Excel::download()` in the `mynova.export.mydata` controller action.
Make sure to protect the new export route with authentication.